# How to efficiently calculate intersection of time ranges?

Tags: javascript, php, performance, logic

I have a somewhat large dataset in the `millions of rows` which consist of a `start time` and an `end time` in the form of a timestamp.

I need to figure out the most efficient or a quite efficient way to calculate how many times these time ranges intersect. The start times are in ascending order however the end times may not be and cannot be.

E.g.

```
1 - Start: 1484725031, End: 1484725045
2 - Start: 1484725033, End: 1484725039
3 - Start: 1484725040, End: 1484725049
```

Here we would have records 1 & 2 which intersect and records 1 and 3 which intersect.

Currently I am simply looping through all the time ranges and then comparing that against the entire list which is really slow...

Any suggestions about how I could improve this?

Comment: Sort them by start time. Then at least you know you don't have to look for earlier ranges, and you can stop once you've found the first one that doesn't intersect your current range.

Comment: Actually which language you are using? Please care to remove unnecessary tags

Comment: I am doing it in PHP however I could also use JavaScript. Apologies, I removed the extra tags.

Comment: They are already in order by start time but the start time of a new one may intersect with a previous end time.

Comment: Do you just need to compute the number of intersections (as in, an integer), or a list of pairs that intersect ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an object for counting an iterate only the whole array and inside until greater start values.

This proposal uses non overlapping start and end times, so for example `start = 5` and `end = 5` does not overlap.

> ```
>           1111111111
> 01234567890123456789   overlapping
> ---                    1
> ------                 3
>    -----               2
>     ------             3
>         ---            2
>          -----         1
>                -----   0
> ```

The result object reads as follow

> ```
> {
>     "0|2": {           // 1 intersection
>         "0|5": true
>     },
>     "0|5": {           // { start: 0, end: 5 } intersects with 3 objects
>         "0|2": true,   // { start: 0, end: 2 } and
>         "3|7": true,   // { start: 3, end: 7 } and
>         "4|9": true    // { start: 4, end: 9 } 
>     },
>     "3|7": {
>         "0|5": true,
>         "4|9": true
>     },
>     "4|9": {
>         "0|5": true,
>         "3|7": true,
>         "8|10": true
>     },
>     "8|10": {
>         "4|9": true,
>         "9|13": true
>     },
>     "9|13": {
>         "8|10": true
>     },
>     "15|19": {}        // no intersection
> }
> ```

```js
var data = [{ start: 0, end: 5 }, { start: 3, end: 7 }, { start: 4, end: 9 }, { start: 8, end: 10 }, { start: 9, end: 13 }, { start: 15, end: 19 }],
    intersections = {};

data.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
    var j = i + 1,
        keyA = a.start + '|' + a.end,
        keyB;

    intersections[keyA] = intersections[keyA] || {};
    while (j < aa.length && aa[j].start < a.end) {    
        keyB = aa[j].start + '|' + aa[j].end;
        intersections[keyA][keyB] = true;
        intersections[keyB] = intersections[keyB] || {};
        intersections[keyB][keyA] = true;
        j++;
    }
});
  
console.log(intersections);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare each possible match and if neither ends before the other begins, they intersect.

```js
var times = [{
  start: 1484725031,
  end: 1484725045
}, {
  start: 1484725033,
  end: 1484725039
}, {
  start: 1484725040,
  end: 1484725049
}];

function findIntersections(times) {
    var newtimes = times.map(function(a, b) {
      //Generate list to track intersections
      var intersections = [];
      a["intersections"] = intersections;
      //Generate a unique id, i use index in array
      a["id"] = b;
      return a;
    });
    //Loop 1
    for (var timeIndexA = 0; timeIndexA < newtimes.length; timeIndexA++) {
      var timeA = newtimes[timeIndexA];
      //Loop 2, notice how we start from Loop 1 + 1. That way we only check each matchup once
      for (var timeIndexB = timeIndexA + 1; timeIndexB < newtimes.length; timeIndexB++) {
        var timeB = newtimes[timeIndexB];
        if (
          //If none end before the other start, they must intersect
          (timeA.end < timeB.start || timeB.end < timeA.start) == false) {
          //Save intersections by index parameter
          timeA.intersections.push(timeB.id);
          timeB.intersections.push(timeA.id);
        }
      }
    }
    //Return result
    console.log(newtimes);
  }
  //Find indexes
var indexed = findIntersections(times);
//log indexes
console.log(indexed);
```

Answer (score 1):

as you intuited, you need to lower the number of comparisons you do. Usually the route is to just not compare I and J if you already compared J and I. that is done easily with following pseudocode :

```
for i over all values{
    for j over 0 to i -1 // alternatively over i+1 to end
       //compare here
    }
}
```

that drops your number of comparisons from N² to N(N-1)/2 (you're still in O(n²) territory but it's better).

Fortunately your array of timespans comes sorted on start times, so you can go one step further :

```
for i over all values{
    for j over i +1 to end of array
       if(intersects){
          //do your thing
       }else{
          // break the looping over j,
          // as no new value will start before times[j]
          break;
       }
    }
}
```

this should dramatically lower the computation time, but in a non-predictable way since it is data-dependant.

Answer (score 1):

```
let timeIntervals = [(start: TimeInterval, end: TimeInterval)]()

var count = 0
for x in 0..<timeIntervals.count {
    for y in x+1..<timeIntervals.count {
        if timeIntervals[x].end >= timeIntervals[y].start {
            count += 1
        } else {
             break
        }
    }
}
```